# All functions solution of $f(f(n))=f(n-1)f(n+1)-2f(n)^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions

I have to find all the functions $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ solution of
$$f(f(n))=f(n-1)f(n+1)-2f(n)^2$$
I have found the solution $f(n)=(-1)^n$. Do other solutions exist?

Comment: Other solutions do exist: $f(n) = 0$ for all $n$, and $f(n) = -1$ for all $n$. But I assume that the question is actually to find all solutions.

Comment: @Dylan, can those cover all if we are allowed to define an arbitrary function such that it differs from all the elementary functions at even in $|\mathbb Z|$ points? I mean, not all of them have to be different in the rest of the $\mathcal R_f$, but I understand there might be other constraints that fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a positive integer $k$ we can define the function $g_k$ to be such that

$g_k(x) := $ $ \begin{cases} 
      -8 & x = k \\
       -2^{2^{d+2}-1} & x = -2^{2^{d+1}-1} , d \in \mathbb{N} \\
      0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
$

---

Now observe that for $x = k$;

$g_k(g_k(k)) = g_k(-8) = -128$

and $g_k(k-1)g_k(k+1)-2g_k(k)^2 = (0)(0)-2(-8)^2 = -128$

Thus $g_k(g_k(k)) = g_k(k-1)g_k(k+1)-2g_k(k)^2  $

---

For $x$ of the form $-2^{2^{d+1}-1} , d \in \mathbb{N}$ note

$g_k(g_k(-2^{2^{d+1}-1})) = -2^{2^{d+3}-1}$ and

$g_k(-2^{2^{d+1}-1}-1)g_k(-2^{2^{d+1}-1}+1)-2g_k(-2^{2^{d+1}-1})^2 = (0)(0)-2(2^{2^{d+2}-1})^2 = -2^{2^{d+3}-1} = g_k(g_k(-2^{2^{d+1}-1}))$

---

For $y$ not in the set $G_k : =$ $\{k\}\cup \{-2^{2^{d+1}-1} | d \in \mathbb{N}\}$ we have

$g_k(g_k(y)) = g_k(0) = 0$ and

$g_k(y-1)g_k(y+1)-2g_k(y)^2 = g_k(y-1)g_k(y+1) = 0$ as either $y-1$ or $y+1$ is not in $G_k$

---

Hence we have showed that the functions $g_k$ form a solution to your desired problem; hence there are infinite number of solutions.

Comment: By modifying the above function we can in fact show that there are an uncountable number of solutions.